# Writing Rust unit tests, but in an independent file

Tags: unit-testing, rust

#### Overview

I want to write some Rust unit tests. The usual way of doing this is to place them in the same file as the code under test. However, this typically makes code files very large, especially if the unit tests are many times longer in terms of their number of lines compared to the code being tested. In my experience this happens quite often. Some tests, even unit tests, might do quite complex and involved testing. I quite often find myself writing several thousands of lines of unit test for a unit of code which is itself only about 1k lines long. This quite often happens if there is a lot of state to setup and this can't just be bundled into a single helper function.

#### Question Summary

How do I move my test code into a separate file without ending up with a strange looking module structure? If I am writing a file containing tests for another file, then both files should be in the same directory. Unless I am missing something obvious, there isn't a straightforward way to do this in Rust. Perhaps I just haven't realized the solution?

#### Example

Consider a simple example, the following library code:

```
lib.rs
  ./my_module/
    mod.rs
    implementation.rs
    ./implementation
    the_test.rs
```

```
// lib.rs
pub mod my_module;
```

```
// my_module/mod.rs
pub mod implementation;
```

```
// my_module/implementation.rs

// silly example function
fn str_to_bool(input: &str) -> bool {

    match input {
        "true" => { return true; }
        _ => { return false; }
    }
}

mod the_test;
```

```
// my_module/implementation/the_test.rs

#[cfg(test)]

#[test]
fn str_to_bool_test() {

    let input = "true";
    assert!(str_to_bool(input) == true);
}
```

It is fairly obvious what the downside of this. While the test code has been moved to a separate file successfully, the test file exists in a subdirectory lower than the code under test.

Ideally, I would prefer to have the test file along side the code under test file.

I can't figure out a good way of doing this however. Moving the module declaration to one level higher doesn't seem like a good solution, because the test module should be a submodule of the module containing the code under test.

Answer (score 0):

The "canonical" solution is to structure it like this:

```
    .\implementation
        mod.rs
        tests.rs
```

or this:

```
    .\implementation.rs
    .\implementation
        tests.rs
```

And add this to the parent module:

```rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests;
```

But if you want a flatter file structure, you can use the [`path` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute):

```
.\implementation.rs
.\implementation.test.rs
```

With this code at the top of `implementation.rs`:

```rs
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "implementation.test.rs"]
mod tests;
```

Comment: Using the `#[path]` attribute is a bad idea, very bad even. And it is definitely not agreed upon that the canonical way is to have `mod.rs`, some people will argue the opposite.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that was bad phrasing on my part. I edited it to include the alternative.

Comment: I don't think using the `#[path]` attribute is a bad idea, otherwise there would probably be a clippy lint for it. `#[path]` is _discouraged_ according to [this style guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/style-team/blob/e72f990b033eb6a2ed7836aa0199a2c3095372c8/guide/guide.md#modules-1), but there aren't any downsides that I know of, except that it is _unconventional_, which is not a bad thing _per se_.

Comment: I will argue that being uncoventional _is_ a bad thing per se, unless you have a very good reason. It'll surprise and confuse everyone reading your code. But to be honest, I'm surprised there isn't even an allow-by-default Clippy lint. Maybe I should suggest one?

Comment: Personally I find having to put tests in a subdirectory with the same name as the unit under test as "confusing"... Using path to put the files in the expected place is less confusing IMO. Going back to the first suggestion, that seems like a good solution. I suppose both `mod.rs` and `test.rs` will declare another `pub mod implementation` or `pub mod implementation_test`? Does that work?

Comment: "I suppose both `mod.rs` and `test.rs` will declare another `pub mod implementation` or `pub mod implementation_test`?" -- if your question is if these modules are created automatically based on the file name, no. You always have to write `mod foo;` or `pub mod foo;` explicitly. This means that Rust will look for the file at `foo.rs` or `foo/mod.rs`, unless you specify a different path with the `#[path = "..."]` attribute. Here's a [blog post](https://aloso.github.io/2021/03/28/module-system.html) I wrote about it a while ago.

Comment: @Aloso I don't expect Rust to somehow write code for me...